# Nhibernate 3.0 and FluentNHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

is anyone building the truck NHibernate and FluentNhibernate together?  How's it working? are you using it for production systems?

How is the Linq support?

Is it nearly ready for release?

Is there a nice and concise way to keep up to date with what is going on in the world of NHibernate?  (ie, without having to read lots of blogs, and mailing lists )

Comment: NHibernate 3 isn't even in alpha yet, I doubt you'll find people using it in production systems.

Comment: its what I'm wondering, there's lots of talk about it.  Sometimes I get the impression lots are running on the latest trunk versions!  Its hard to know.

Comment: 26 Jul 2010 NHibernate 3 Alpha1 came out.  Just Updating the space time continuum.  Would love a simpler package manager to build trunk versions of FNH + NH though.

Comment: I find hornget to be an easy way to get trunk builds (see the answer below).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find trunk FNH builds here: http://hornget.net/packages/orm/fluentnhibernate/fluentnhibernate-trunk (I haven't tried it as I don't use Fluent)

NHibernate 3.0 is pretty stable and the new Linq provider is very good, with an excelent coverage of the possible Linq constructs and clever, non-intrusive support of NHibernate specific concerns (*caching*, *fetching*)

I'd use it in production without much concern; being in a "pre-alpha" state only reflects the seriousness of the project team, as the current state is more similar to that of a Visual Studio **RC** than a CTP or Beta.

**Update (2010-12-05)**: NHibernate 3 was released yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

Directly on FNH site, under the download section, you can find the "Latest Master Build"

http://fluentnhibernate.org/downloads

If it may help